# Flex and several xsd's

Tags: apache-flex, soap, service, xsd

I'm using Flex and am trying to access a Web Service.

That web service references several XSD files. Those XSD files follow this "order":

```
<call.xsd>   
   <input.xsd>
   </input.xsd>
   <output.xsd>
      <struct1.xsd>
      </struct1.xsd>
      <struct2.xsd>
      </struct2.xsd>
      <struct3.xsd>
      </struct3.xsd>
   </output.xsd>
</call.xsd>
```

On the Network Monitor there are thousands of requests to the struct XSD's and there are no result or fault events....

Here's how I'm declariong the web service:

```
<s:WebService id="myService" wsdl="http://localhost:9080/Path/WebServiceName.wsdl"
   concurrency="single">

   <s:operation name="call_WebServiceOperation" result="resultHandler(event)"
       fault="faultHandler(event)" resultFormat="object" /> 

</s:WebService>
```

Here's how I'me initiating it:

```
public var request:Request

private function init():void {                      
   request = new Request("param1", "param2", "param3", "param4", "param5", "param6");
   myService.call_WebServiceOperation(request);
}
```

And here's jow I'm handling the events:

```
protected function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
{
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
} -> Debugging here

protected function faultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void
{
   Alert.show(event.fault.faultString);
}
```

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: Does your web service return anything?>  Are you sure you set up your result / fault handlers correctly?  I think you should show some Flex code.

Comment: I updated my post with the code I'm using in Flex

Comment: The Web Services I'm consuming are Java based and return and receive DataObjects... Could this be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this some time ago and despite no one seems to have this problem or even care about it :-P ... here's the solution.

As I've said I've created the data model on Websphere Integration Developer.

Ehen we create a tree data structure such as:

Each element is created as an XSD file, instead of in the same xsd.

So what I did was copy every  element of every XSD file to the  XSD.

Voila this worked like a charm.

In conclusion it would be nice if in Websphere Integration Developer we could set each element to be saved on the same XSD, because I had to make this changes directly on the XSD files.

Hope no one comes across this problem in the future but if it does at least this is my advice...

Answer (score 0):

I continue to have this problem and posted a thread on Adobe.

In case someone is interested:

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/804345